# Correlated subquery to find employees earning more than average salary in their departments

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am writing an Oracle query to find employees who earn more than the average salary within their departments. I need to display the last_name,employee_ID, salary, department_id and average salary of that department. I have written this query but I am not getting the desired answer. Can please someone tell me, where I am making the mistake

```
select last_name,employee_id,salary,department_id,avg(salary) 
  from employees e1
 where salary > (select avg(salary) 
                   from employees e2 
                  where e1.department_id=e2.department_id)
 group by last_name,employee_id,salary,department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with med as
         (select department_id, avg(salary) avgSalary
            from employees
           group by department_id)
        select last_name, employee_id, salary, e.department_id, avgSalary
          from employees e, med m
         where e.department_id = m.department_id and e.salary > m.avgSalary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing to display the average dept salary in the results, a correlated subquery is not the way to go.

You could calculate the average salary in a separate query and then join to it:

```
with emp as (select 1 emp_id, 'bob' name, 10000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 2 emp_id, 'joe' name, 20000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 3 emp_id, 'fred' name, 10000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 4 emp_id, 'ivy' name, 20000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 5 emp_id, 'ann' name, 30000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 6 emp_id, 'jo' name, 20000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 7 emp_id, 'fion' name, 30000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 8 emp_id, 'alan' name, 40000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 9 emp_id, 'eve' name, 50000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 10 emp_id, 'rob' name, 10000 salary, 4 dept_id from dual)
select emp1.name,
       emp1.emp_id,
       emp1.salary,
       emp1.dept_id,
       emp2.average_dept_salary
from   emp emp1
       inner join (select dept_id,
                          avg(salary) average_dept_salary
                   from   emp
                   group by dept_id) emp2
           on (emp1.dept_id = emp2.dept_id)
where emp1.salary > emp2.average_dept_salary;

NAME     EMP_ID     SALARY    DEPT_ID AVERAGE_DEPT_SALARY
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
joe           2      20000          1               15000
ann           5      30000          2               20000
alan          8      40000          3               35000
eve           9      50000          3               35000
```

But personally, I would use an analytic function to get the average salary instead, and then filter using that. This way, you don't have to scan the table twice:

```
with emp as (select 1 emp_id, 'bob' name, 10000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 2 emp_id, 'joe' name, 20000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 3 emp_id, 'fred' name, 10000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 4 emp_id, 'ivy' name, 20000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 5 emp_id, 'ann' name, 30000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 6 emp_id, 'jo' name, 20000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 7 emp_id, 'fion' name, 30000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 8 emp_id, 'alan' name, 40000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 9 emp_id, 'eve' name, 50000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 10 emp_id, 'rob' name, 10000 salary, 4 dept_id from dual),
     res as (select name,
                    emp_id,
                    salary,
                    dept_id,
                    avg(salary) over (partition by dept_id) average_dept_salary
             from   emp)
select name,
       emp_id,
       salary,
       dept_id,
       average_dept_salary
from   res
where  salary > average_dept_salary;

NAME     EMP_ID     SALARY    DEPT_ID AVERAGE_DEPT_SALARY
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
joe           2      20000          1               15000
ann           5      30000          2               20000
alan          8      40000          3               35000
eve           9      50000          3               35000
```

---

And here is a way you could do what you want via a correlated query (two, actually), but I really, really would advise against using this. For a start, now there are 3 pass throughs of the same table!

```
with emp as (select 1 emp_id, 'bob' name, 10000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 2 emp_id, 'joe' name, 20000 salary, 1 dept_id from dual union all
             select 3 emp_id, 'fred' name, 10000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 4 emp_id, 'ivy' name, 20000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 5 emp_id, 'ann' name, 30000 salary, 2 dept_id from dual union all
             select 6 emp_id, 'jo' name, 20000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 7 emp_id, 'fion' name, 30000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 8 emp_id, 'alan' name, 40000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 9 emp_id, 'eve' name, 50000 salary, 3 dept_id from dual union all
             select 10 emp_id, 'rob' name, 10000 salary, 4 dept_id from dual)
select emp1.name,
       emp1.emp_id,
       emp1.salary,
       emp1.dept_id,
       (select avg(salary) 
        from   emp emp3
        where  emp1.dept_id = emp3.dept_id) average_dept_salary
from   emp emp1
where  emp1.salary > (select avg(salary) 
                      from   emp emp2
                      where  emp1.dept_id = emp2.dept_id);

NAME     EMP_ID     SALARY    DEPT_ID AVERAGE_DEPT_SALARY
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
joe           2      20000          1               15000
ann           5      30000          2               20000
alan          8      40000          3               35000
eve           9      50000          3               35000
```

Comment: can u please answer this question using correlated subquery

Comment: Why do you need a correlated subquery? I mean, you could use the correlated query to do the filtering, but in order to display the average salary in the results, you're going to need to do a select just to get the salary. Why bother, when there are better, more performant ways?